# How to move gallery html into theme to update html?

Tags: magento2, theme, gallery

I am trying to make changes to the following file but unsure how I can copy it over the to theme? As I do not want to edit the core gallery file?

> lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html

I've moved this to:

> app/design/frontend/theme/theme/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html

But still seems to be using the lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html file?

How can I get edit this file from within my theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be the right location.

Have you removed your `pub/static` & `var/*` and executed `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`?

Comment: Thanks, removing the `pub/static` and `var/` and running the `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` has made my changes appear.